# php strlen shows different length of array elements

Tags: php, strlen

I am having a problem. I have a string in a variable. I split the string in to an array using explode function. But strlen function shows different lengths when I echo the string as an array element and echo the same string in strlen function. Below is my code

```
 echo $schedule = 'Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday, Early Evening 6pm-9pm Wednesday';
    $scr = explode(",",$schedule);
    $sc = array_map('trim', $scr);
    print_r($sc);
    echo strlen($sc[0]);
    echo $sc[0];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'string "Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday" has '.strlen('Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday'). ' chars<br />';
if(in_array('Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday', $sc)){ echo 'yes'; } else { echo 'no'; }
```

and here is output:

```
        Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday, Early Evening 6pm-9pm Wednesday

        Array ( [0] =>
        Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday [1] => Early Evening 6pm-9pm Wednesday

        ) 
    151 //length of first element of array
        Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday //first element of an array
        string "Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday" has 29 chars
no //I need yes here
```

Comment: When I execute this very code, I get the expected result. What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: Are you getting yes at the end. I am getting no for this if statement. if(in_array('Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday', $sc)){ echo 'yes'; } else { echo 'no'; }

Comment: It is something else: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5f94476ca37fa91c642572116ffe114f7401860

Comment: Actually I am getting string through a function which is $schedule = bp_get_the_profile_field_value();. So in my actual code which I am executing, instead of a string I have a function bp_get_the_profile_field_value() and this function gives me the string. so here is my actual code which is not working http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58607a646367007a5f7433dbcb71ab8c50a53beb

Comment: Should I edit my question?

Comment: @Riz ah, the dangers of assumptions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your string contains HTML tags that you just don't see in your browser.

Try adding

```
$sc = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $scr);
```

after your third line to make them visible, or view page source of your output.

Comment: I think we are reaching our solution. Using above code I can see html elements along with my string. Array ( [0] => <p><a href="http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/?s=Early+Evening+6pm-9pm+Tuesday" rel="nofollow">Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday</a> [1] => <a href="http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/?s=Early+Evening+6pm-9pm+Wednesday" rel="nofollow">Early Evening 6pm-9pm Wednesday</a></p> ). Please tell me how to remove these html elements so that I can get simple "string Early Evening 6pm-9pm Tuesday, Early Evening 6pm-9pm Wednesday".

Comment: Thanks have done it. This helped me very much. I used strip_tags() to remove the html chars.

Comment: To remove simply do `$sc = array_map('strip_tags', $sc);` on line 4 (and first remove the line with `htmlspecialchars` you added for me.